# How to program NAO robot in python using the DCM module

Tags: nao-robot

I'm working with the NAO robot on generating walkings.

I have used the function angleInterpolation() and it worked well for offline trajectories, but now I need to use the dcm module to send the joints trajectories in real time but when I do it it's like the movement of the joints is very rigid (very different from angleInterpolation). Has anyone worked in NAO robot, specifically with the dcm module that could help me?

I'm programming in python.

(Sorry for my bad English).

I have try using dcm.setAlias() and a time delay to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The movement are more rigid because angleInterpolation() generate splines, while dcm handle direct position (=>linear). If it's what you need, you need to modify your order to damp start and stop.

Btw working with dcm is more dangerous, as there's less protections. Another alternative is using ALMotion.setAngles functions family.